# What does exactly means "User was removed" with -5 reputation loss?

Tags: support, reputation

I discovered this change this morning, and was surprised. I'm just curious about the meaning of this reputation loss :
`-5 User was removed`

Thanks for your enlightenment.

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125740/238438

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It simply means that a user is no longer on the site (their account was removed by request or by violating site rules). When an account is removed, so are the votes the user has cast, be it upvotes or downvotes.

Read more on meta.so, [What does "user was removed" mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126470/226253).